# Using Social Media Dashboard Sample From MSDN

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am trying use a sample[(Link1)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Social-Media-Dashboard-135436da/view/Discussions#content) from MSDN. 
The project solution consists of three projects: Windows 8, windows phone,Portable Class Library.
I am trying workout for Windows 8 with this [(link2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2013/05/13/displaying-html-content-in-a-richtextblock.aspx).
 The description under the project specifies we need these references From NuGet.
[image]

I added these references to my Visual Studio.
Still I am getting some errors about namespaces

> using SocialMediaDashboard.PCL.Common;
>
> using SocialMediaDashboard.W8.EnableLiveTile.TileContent;
>
> using SocialMediaDashboard.PCL.Helpers;

I gave StartUp project as Windows 8.

I am getting errors like

> The type or namespace name 'EnableLiveTile' does not exist in the namespace 'SocialMediaDashboard.W8'

[image]

It may looks easy But I am wondering about this sample from few hours, So please give me your suggestions regarding this.

Comment: I can't see your image full view. It won't let me click to zoom so I cannot see anything that's written on the image. What is your actual namespace? Did you change it? And did you download all required samples and did you download this one? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Social-Media-Dashboard-135436da

Comment: Thanks for reply..
May I know which Image your asking about,(Visual Studio or Webpage link) 
I am missing the reference `SocialMediaDashboard.PCL`.
Yes, I hope I added references into VS,Please check in reference folder in Visual studio screenshot what I uploded.